# while initialize the spring boot project IntelliJ idea it is asking to select the dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-initializr

[[image]] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Hu8.jpg)I am new to spring-boot. After installing the Spring Initializer plugin, I started to create my very first Spring Boot project. While initializing the spring boot project, IntelliJ IDEA asks to select the dependency.

can anyone help to solve this problem ?

Comment: Looks like the issue is caused by [Spring Initializr and Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-initializr-and-assistant) plugin. I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://github.com/eltonsandre/intellij-spring-assistant/issues or use IntelliJ Ultimate which has built-in Spring support.

Comment: Thank you, I have installed and used IntelliJ Ultimate now it's resolved. But I think so, the problem is in the IntelliJ community version and plugin version, and I also raised the issues regarding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

while initialize the spring boot project IntelliJ idea it is asking to select the dependency

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).